# PHP APC Cache - Will it work out of the box for dynamic content?

Tags: php, caching, apc

I was wondering if PHP APC Cache would work out of the box for dynamic content?

Basically, I am hoping to use APC cache to speed up my site but my listings page is dynamic and can change within minutes (users adding listing or removing listings) and each listing result will vary for users based on their location.

Can I run APC out of the box to handle what I have mentioned above or will it cache the page and results will never change?

Will it be wise for me to add **apc.stat = [1|0]** to apc.ini?

Sorry if the questions are novice but it is the first time I will be working with APC.

Thanks.

Comment: apc caches the "compiled" php code. it doesn't cache output

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you understands as dynamic.

If your php **code** is static and doesn't change, you can use apc or opcache (if you run 5.5+) to its fullest. It doesn't matter **what** the code generates as apc is not used to cache the output("quoted" from Marc B's comment).

If your php code changes [you likely made something wrong] you could still use apc, als long as you don't disable the timechecks `apc.stat`.

Manipulating apc.stat is a good choice if you can guarantee that after each deploy the cache is purged (manual function call during the deploy process or webserver restart) and the codebase doesn't change between deploys.